# Biased estimates of Hurst exponent in R/S analysis

Tags: time-series, references, stationarity, long-range-dependence, hurst-exponent

I've used the standard R/S algorithm for estimating the Hurst exponent in *Mathematica**, and tested it on fBm and fGn for $H\in\{0.05,0.1,\ldots,0.95\}$, generating 1000 time series for each $H$. The results, in form of violin plots, are as follows:

[image]

While for fGn the performance is somewhat ok (although anti-persistent processes are systematically overestimated), I was surprised to see the awful performance in case of fBm. I hadn't found anywhere an indication that R/S is not suitable for nonstationary data, so I always assumed it's a universal algorithm.

After seeing these results, I've done some more digging and only found this paper: [Bias in estimating fractal dimension with the rescaled-range (R/S) technique](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02089240) suggesting that $H>1$ is a sign of nonstationarity.

Is this bias (for both fBm and fGn) something well-known that I've just been constantly missing? Has it been thoroughly examined, and is there some study to reference?

I have also generated a few fBm (and fGn through differencing) and estimated their $H$ using `R`'s `hurstexp` function, finding a similar pattern; so it seems it's a real phenomenon, not a sloppy implementation.

---

*http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/HurstExponentOfStockPrice/

Comment: Others [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/415162/72352) obtain the same result.